# How to make full circle when it comes to the end in ng-circle-progress?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to count down from 60 to zero.

I use [ng-circle-progress](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress) (Angular package) to do that.

The problem is something with my calculation not end up right.

I try to do it with those options - but the number is 100, 99, 98... (instead of 60, 59, 58..):

```
 options = {
    percent: 100,
    radius: 60,
    backgroundPadding: 7,
    outerStrokeWidth: 2,
    innerStrokeWidth: 2,
    space: -2,
    outerStrokeColor: "#808080",
    innerStrokeColor: "#e7e8ea",
    showBackground: true,
    titleFontSize: 12,
    subtitleFontSize: 20,
    showUnits: false,
    showSubtitle: false,
    animationDuration: 60000,
    startFromZero: true
  };
```

I also try to set `percent` to 60 but the circle is not complete until the end and the countdown goes more to negative numbers:

```
 options = {
    percent: 60,
    radius: 60,
    backgroundPadding: 7,
    outerStrokeWidth: 2,
    innerStrokeWidth: 2,
    space: -2,
    outerStrokeColor: "#808080",
    innerStrokeColor: "#e7e8ea",
    showBackground: true,
    titleFontSize: 12,
    subtitleFontSize: 20,
    showUnits: false,
    showSubtitle: false,
    animationDuration: 60000,
    startFromZero: true,
    titleFormat: (percent) => {
      return `${60 - percent}`;
    }
  };
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-boyd-qrj9b?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Surely the starting percent needs to be 100, but the value to *display* should be `(100 / percent) * 60`?

Comment: `titleFormat: (percent) => {  return `${(100 / percent) * 60}`;  }` - not works :(

Comment: Could you expand on *"not works"*? It seems like you have a mathematical problem right now, not a programming one.

Comment: And sorry; that should be percent / 100 not 100 / percent